# Show / Hide a Node within a stage

Tags: javafx, fxml

I am aware that there are already answers for this question but somehow, it was not able to solve my problem.

When I click the textfield in IMAGE1, I want the keyboard FXML(IMAGE2) to appear as is in IMAGE3. But the thing is, I can't seem to find the solution. How do I do this?

I need your help please.

IMAGE1

[image]

IMAGE2

[image]

IMAGE3

[image]

Comment: I have seen codes that switch 2 FXML files but I was unable to figure my way with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am experimenting with something similar, here is what I came up with (one of many possible solutions):

You need to wrap your main layout (IMAGE1) in a `StackPane`. Its usage is to *overlay* what needs be overlaid (the keyboard in your case). The keyboard is placed in another pane (a `VBox` in the following example). The `VBox`:

- is placed in the `StackPane` *after* the main layout to sit on top of it
- is given a maximum height, so that it doesn't fill the entire window
- is given a `translateY` equal to the height
- and bottom alignment

The relevant code n FXML:

```
<VBox fx:id="statusContainer" maxHeight="100.0" prefHeight="100.0"
    translateY="100.0" StackPane.alignment="BOTTOM_LEFT" />
```

This will always be outside of the view. Toggling the keyboard requires 2 `TranslateTransition`s (can it be done with 1, I wonder?), one to move the keyboard up, one down.

The example code:

1) Java:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javafx.animation.TranslateTransition;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class Test1 extends Application
{
    @FXML private VBox statusContainer;

    private TranslateTransition showStatus;
    private TranslateTransition hideStatus;
    boolean showsStatus = false;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            StackPane page = (StackPane) FXMLLoader.load(this.getClass().getResource("test1.fxml"));
            Scene scene = new Scene(page);

            primaryStage.setTitle(this.getClass().getName());
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.sizeToScene();
            primaryStage.show();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            Logger.getLogger(this.getClass().getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
        }
    }

    @FXML void initialize() {
        showStatus = new TranslateTransition(Duration.millis(250), statusContainer);
        showStatus.setByY(-100.0);
        showStatus.setOnFinished(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                showsStatus = true;
            }
        });
        hideStatus = new TranslateTransition(Duration.millis(250), statusContainer);
        hideStatus.setByY(100.0);
        hideStatus.setOnFinished(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                showsStatus = false;
            }
        });
    }

    public void toggleStatus() {
        if( showsStatus ) {
            showStatus.stop();
            hideStatus.play();
        }
        else {
            hideStatus.stop();
            showStatus.play();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

2) FXML (call it `test1.fxml` to match the code):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.net.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.paint.*?>

<StackPane id="StackPane" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" fx:controller="fancymsg.FancyMsg1">
  <children>
    <AnchorPane prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0">
      <children>
        <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#toggleStatus" text="Status" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="50.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="100.0" />
      </children>
    </AnchorPane>
    <VBox fx:id="statusContainer" maxHeight="100.0" prefHeight="100.0" translateY="100.0" StackPane.alignment="BOTTOM_LEFT" />
  </children>
  <stylesheets>
    <URL value="@test1.css" />
  </stylesheets>
</StackPane>
```

3) The CSS for the `VBox` to stand out (call it `test1.css`):

```
#statusContainer {
    -fx-background-color: -fx-color;
}
```

Comment: This is a great tip! Thanks! I have another question though @Nikos, how do you actually load the fxml file for, let's say the keyboard fxml, to the VBox?

Comment: You can either include it in the main FXML (dumb but simple) Or load it just like the main, have a `@FXML` property for the `VBox` in the main controller and do `vbox.getChildren().add(keyboard)`.

Comment: This might sound demanding @Nikos Paraskevopoulos but can you actually show me how the syntax for it is done? please :)

Comment: SOLVED IT! thru this lines of code:

AnchorPane a = (AnchorPane) FXMLLoader.load(this.getClass().getResource("view/keyboard.fxml"));
           vBox.getChildren().add(a);

Thank you @Nikos for the help! It means a lot!

Answer (score 0):

An mcve version of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21093831/3992939)
can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56715777/3992939)

[image]