# Interaction of two Controllers in JavaFX

Tags: binding, controller, javafx-2, model-binding, javafx-8

Good day! I would like to ask how these particular situation is done in JAVAFX.

I have made a layout as being pointed out here [(link to layout question)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21091351/call-another-fxml-within-a-stage)

My question is since the keyboard layout is [image: keyBoardLayout]   from a different FXML with a different Controller class and with the mainLayout having a different FXML with its own controller class, [image: mainLayout] , how do you code such thing that when I press key **'A'**, it will display on the textfield found in the mainLayout? Does it have to do with bindings? If so, how? Please?

Comment: Are you using JavaFX 8 or 2.2?

Comment: javafx 8, Sorry for the confusion on my tags

Answer (score 1):

bear in mind that JavaFX and FXML follow the MVC principle.

an easy (although perhaps not optimal) solution would look like this:

```
public class Main extends Application {

  @Override
  public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    FXMLLoader layout1Loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("layout1.fxml"));
    FXMLLoader layout2loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("layout2.fxml"));

    Node layout1 = (Node) layout1Loader.load();
    Node layout2 = (Node) layout2loader.load();

    final Layout1Controller l1Controller = layout1Loader.getController();
    final Layout2Controller l2Controller = layout2loader.getController();

    l2Controller.but2.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
      @Override
      public void handle(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        l1Controller.toggleStatus(actionEvent);
      }
    });


    Parent root = (Parent) layout1;
    Scene scene = new Scene(root);

    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
  }
...
}
```

Comment: I get a NullException Error.

Comment: of course you must replace the fxml in my example with *your* fxml file and make sure that your fxml *do* have a controller set.

Comment: Still NullError @Sebastian

Comment: I posted a similar concept of my code @Sebastian , not the one on the layout though of same principle because the original one has longer codes to paste.

Comment: ,in what class below shall I put this on? @Sebastian

Comment: Also @Sebastian InvocationTargetException error on the 
Node layout1 = layout1Loader.load();
Node layout2 = layout2loader.load();

codes..

Comment: this means that he couldn't load your fxml file. I tried your code above and it works like a charm. I edited my answer again. I already spend to much time on this answer than I should, so I would suggest you follow some basic javafx fxml tutorials before getting any further. For example: http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/get_started/fxml_tutorial.htm

Comment: method toggleStatus() isnt the correct method . Thanks anyway

Comment: well I think the main question, how to get two controller from different fxml files to communicate with each other, was answered / demonstrated. I think that you can adapt this easily now.